# Rails AREL .where statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an AREL query:

```
@group.members.where('member_id != ?', 4)
```

As expected, this query returns all members with an ID not equal to 4.

How would I build the same type of query to omit multiple IDs?  For example:

```
@group.members.where('member_id != ?', [4 3])
```

Which would ideally return all members with an ID not equal to either 4 or 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
@group.members.where('member_id NOT IN (?)', [4, 3] )
```

This also work if you pass only one integer (not an array):

```
@group.members.where('member_id NOT IN (?)', 12)
```

Comment: Mr. Yoshiji - you, my friend, are generous for sharing your knowledge.  Thank you!