# ActiveRecord where field = ? array of possible values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to do

```
Model.where('id = ?', [array of values])
```

How do I accomplish this look up without chaining OR statements together?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099558/rails-arel-where-statement) it appears to be done using an SQL `in` statement:

```
Model.where('id IN (?)', [array of values])
```

Or more simply, as kdeisz pointed out (Using Arel to create the SQL query):

```
Model.where(id: [array of values])
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `Model.where(id: [array of values])`

Comment: Model.where("id in (?)", [1..8]) does not seemt o be working for me. any ideas?

Comment: You don't need the square brackets, `1..8` is already array-like.

Comment: Will this syntax automatically escape single quotes within the [array of values]?

Comment: When my array is big enough, the method expend a lot of time. How could you do that with really big arrays?

Answer (score 22):

From the [ActiveRecord Query Interface guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions)

> If you want to find records using the IN expression you can pass an array to the conditions hash:

```
Client.where(orders_count: [1,3,5])
```

Comment: The link in this answer is currently not working, should be https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions

Answer (score 6):

For readability, this can be simplified even further, to:

```
Model.find_by(id: [array of values])
```

This is equivalent to using `where`, but more explicit:

```
Model.where(id: [array of values])
```

Comment: `find_by` actually is `where().take`. `Model.find_by(id: [1, 2, 3])` will only return `Model(id: 1)`

Comment: another option if looking for just a single record instead of the array that meets the criteria, `find_by_id([1, 2, 3])`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'in' operator:

```
Model.in(id: [array of values])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a query in mongoid this is the one`Model.where(:field.in => ["value1", "value2"] ).all.to_a`

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'small' difference between **where** and **find_by**.

**find_by** will return just one record if found otherwise it will be nil.

> Finds the first record matching the specified conditions. There is no implied ordering so if order matters, you should specify it yourself.
>   If no record is found, returns nil.

```
  def find_by(*args)
      where(*args).take
    rescue RangeError
      nil
  end
```

meanwhile **where** it will return an relation

> Returns a new relation, which is the result of filtering the current relation
>     according to the conditions in the arguments.

So, in your situation the appropriate code is:

```
Model.where(id: [array of values])
```