# SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: REGEXP rails rspec

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, sqlite, ruby-2.1

In my project, I have different time slices. These time slices have names such as "00-04", "04-08", "08-12", "12-16", "16-20" and "20-24" and more. I wanted to get all the time slices objects with aforementioned names. So, I programmed following:

```
time_slice_names = ["00-04", "04-08", "08-12", "12-16", "16-20", "20-24"]
time_slices = TimeSlice.where('name REGEXP ?', time_slice_names.join("|"))
```

time_slices gives me correct objects in my development mode. However, when I run the test, I have the errors as:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
 SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: REGEXP: SELECT "time_slices".* FROM "time_slices"  WHERE (name REGEXP '00-04|04-08|08-12|12-16|16-20|20-24')
```

My database.yml is as follows:

```
  development:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: development 
    encoding: utf8
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000

  test:
    adapter: sqlite3
    database: db/test.sqlite3
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000
```

I am aware that my test environment uses sqlite3 whereas my development environment uses mysql2. Is there anyway where I can perform the above mentioned query on both mysql2 and sqlite3?

Comment: I find it better to use the same DB adapter for dev/test/prod. However, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query) out (ignore the accepted answer).

Comment: @sadiksha Me too don't have much knowledge on the SQLite part. So if it works with MySQL and not SQLite, n the error clearly says that SQLite doesn't have implemented that regexp function. So better use the same Db for all envs as ndn suggested.

Comment: Thanks you and @ndn, for this case I used the query for handling arrays. I will definitely consider your suggestion.

Comment: @SadikshaGautam it would be best if you post an answer with your current solution and accept it for future users to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to different answers in [How to turn on REGEXP in SQLite3 and Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839204/how-to-turn-on-regexp-in-sqlite3-and-rails-3-1), `regexp()` is not by default defined in Sqlite3. You have to install a native extension which adds this functionality to Sqlite3.

However, your query can be done without using Regular expressions.

```
time_slice_names = ["00-04", "04-08", "08-12", "12-16", "16-20", "20-24"]
time_slices = TimeSlice.where(name: time_slice_names)
```

The internal database adapter (mysql or sqlite3) should understand this and convert it to supporting `where field in (x, y, z)` query.

More information available [ActiveRecord where field = ? array of possible values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954500/activerecord-where-field-array-of-possible-values/28954548#28954548)